# In pandas, how do I replace label IDs with label strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (sample) dataframe that looks like this:

```
labelID      count
1            185302
2            137777
3            247434
4            136571
5             39724
6             46959
7             88471
8            109182
9             65326
```

I'd like to replace the `labelID` column with the label names, so that I have something like this:

```
labelID      count
label 1      185302
label 2      137777
label 3      247434
label 4      136571
label 5       39724
label 6       46959
label 7       88471
label 8      109182
label 9       65326
```

I've looked at [Renaming / mapping labels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#renaming-mapping-labels), but this seems to be for columns headers and indexes. I want to rename the actual values. How do I do this?

Comment: Sorry are these values occurring more than once? Are you just wanting to add the label string or are you looking to replace values?

Comment: The values in `labelID` will only occur once. This dataframe is the result of a `groupby` so I should only have each one time. I want to replace the IDs with a useful string, because I'll be plotting these for a presentation and the label is much more useful than an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions) to replace values in a series (or, if you wanted to replace across the entire dataframe you could use `applymap`).

---

```
import pandas as pd

label_map = {
    1: 'label 1',
    2: 'label 2',
    3: 'label 3',
    4: 'label 4',
    5: 'label 5',
    6: 'label 6',
    7: 'label 7',
    8: 'label 8',
    9: 'label 9',
}

df = pd.read_clipboard()
df['labelID'] = df['labelID'].map(label_map)
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

---

You need a dictionary that maps the values to the labels. This dictionary is then passed to the `map` function, which is applied on the Series you want to relabel

```
df['labelID'] = df['labelID'].map(label_map)
```

This changes the dataframe to use the new labels (I've printed it without the index to match the format in your question)

```
labelID   count
label 1  185302
label 2  137777
label 3  247434
label 4  136571
label 5   39724
label 6   46959
label 7   88471
label 8  109182
label 9   65326
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the type of the column to `str` (assuming the dtype is numeric here) using `astype` and then just add the prefix:

```
In [35]:
df['labelID'] = 'label ' + df['labelID'].astype(str)
df

Out[35]:
   labelID   count
0  label 1  185302
1  label 2  137777
2  label 3  247434
3  label 4  136571
4  label 5   39724
5  label 6   46959
6  label 7   88471
7  label 8  109182
8  label 9   65326
```

Comment: This looks like it'd only work for my example. If my labels weren't easily built using the ids (for example: 1 = "Brown", 2 = "Red", 3 = "Purple"), would I have to do this for each possible value?

Comment: Then you'd have to `map` like the other answer but it was a little unclear to me hence my comment, your sample was a bit too basic really